# Using Python and Selenium to scrape hard-to-find web tables

Tags: python, r, selenium, web-scraping, knitr

I've been using Python and Selenium to scrape data from specific state health web pages and output the table to a local CSV.

I've had a lot of success on several other states using similar code.  But, I have hit a state that is using what appears to be R to create dynamic dashboards that I can't really access using my normal methods.

I've spent a great deal of time combing through StackOverflow . . . I've checked to see if there's an iframe to switch to, but, I'm just not seeing the data I want located in the iframe on the page.

I can find the table info easy enough using Chrome's "Inspect" feature.  But, starting from the original URL, the data I need is not on that page and I can't find a source URL for the the table.  I've even used Fiddler to see if there's a call somewhere.

So, I'm not sure what to do.  I can see the data--but, I don't know where it is to tell Selenium and BS4 where to access it.

The page is here:  https://coronavirus.utah.gov/case-counts/

The page takes a while to load . . . I've had other states have this issue and Selenium could work through it.

The table I need looks like this:
[image]

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is the code I've been using . . . it doesn't work here, but, the structure is very similar to that which has worked for other states.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

st = 'ut'
url = 'https://coronavirus.utah.gov/case-counts/'
timeout = 20

# Spawn the webpage using Selenium
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'D:\Work\Python\utilities\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.minimize_window()
driver.get(url)

# Let page load . . . it takes a while
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located()((By.ID, "total-number-of-lab-confirmed-covid-19-cases-living-in-utah")))

# Now, scrape table
html = driver.find_element_by_id("total-number-of-lab-confirmed-covid-19-cases-living-in-utah")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table', id='#DataTables_Table_0')
df = pd.read_html(str(table))
exec(st + "_counts = df[0]")

tmp_str = f"{st}_counts.to_csv(r'D:\Work\Python\projects\Covid_WebScraping\output\{st}_covid_cnts_' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')) + '.csv'"
file_path = tmp_str + ", index=False)"

exec(file_path)

# Close the chrome web driver
driver.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried using [Katalon Recorder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/katalon-recorder-selenium/ljdobmomdgdljniojadhoplhkpialdid?hl=en-US)? If you can find it in the DOM, then Katalon should be able to generate a Selenium xpath that you can use to access values in the table. Might look something like `//table[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody/tr/td`

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up.  I didn't know about that.  It allowed me to see which frame the table was in (driver.switch_to_frame(0)), but, now the page just hangs.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to the get the information I needed.

Thanks to Julian Stanley for letting me know about the Katalon Recorder product.  That allowed me to see what the iframe was where the table was.

Using my old method of finding an element by CSS or XPATH was causing a Pickle error due to locked thread.  I have no clue how to deal with that . . . but, it caused the entire project to just hang.

But, I was able to get the text/HTML of the table via attribute.  After that, I just read it with BS4 as usual.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

st = 'ut'
url = 'https://coronavirus.utah.gov/case-counts/'
timeout = 20

# Spawn the webpage using Selenium
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'D:\Work\Python\utilities\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
#driver.minimize_window()
driver.get(url)


# Let page load . . . it takes a while
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)

# Get name of frame (or use index=0)
frames = [frame.get_attribute('id') for frame in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')]

# Switch to frame
#driver.switch_to_frame("coronavirus-dashboard")
driver.switch_to_frame(0)

# Now, scrape table
html = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#DataTables_Table_0_wrapper').get_attribute('innerHTML')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table', id='DataTables_Table_0')
df = pd.read_html(str(table))
exec(st + "_counts = df[0]")

tmp_str = f"{st}_counts.to_csv(r'D:\Work\Python\projects\Covid_WebScraping\output\{st}_covid_cnts_' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')) + '.csv'"
file_path = tmp_str + ", index=False)"

exec(file_path)

# Close the chrome web driver
driver.close()
```